# A question involving orders modulo a prime and $\phi(p) = p - 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}$**Notation**.  Let $e(p, B)$ stand for the exponent of the prime $p$ in the prime factorization of the natural number $B$.  If $p$ doesn't appear in the prime factorization of $B$, then $e(p,B) = 0$.

**Question**.  Let $x, p$ be coprime and $p$ an odd prime.  If $e(2,\ord(x,p)) = e(2, p - 1)$, is it true that $x^{(p-1)/2} = -1 \bmod{p}$?  I don't know the answer, but I would think so.  (I haven't managed to prove it and I'm not seeing it with clarity, so perhaps it is not true.)

**What do I know**?  I know that $e(2,\ord(x,p)) = e(2, p - 1)$, then $x^{(p - 1)/2} \bmod{p}$ cannot be 1 because $(p - 1)/2$ is not a multiple of $\ord(x,p)$.  (By dividing $(p - 1)$ by $2$, we removed the last factor of $2$ that would still make $(p - 1)$ a multiple of $\ord(x,p)$).

**What I don't know**.  Although I see $x^{(p - 1)/2} \neq 1 \bmod{p}$, I don't see why it is always $x^{(p - 1)/2} = -1 \bmod{p} = (p - 1) \bmod{p}$.

**Solution** after @CardboardBox's answer.  Applying Fermat's little theorem, we know $y = x^{(p-1)/2}$ satisfies $y^2 \equiv 1 \bmod{p}$ and that implies $(y - 1)(y + 1) \equiv 0 \bmod{p}$.  That leads to the conclusion $y \equiv \pm 1 \bmod{p}$ which means I can't say for sure $y \equiv -1 \bmod{p}$.  However, in the original problem, we know $y = x^{(p-1)/2} \bmod{p}$ cannot be 1.  Therefore, $y \equiv -1 \bmod{p}$ is the only possibility left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element $y = x^{(p-1)/2}$ satisfies $y^2 \equiv 1 \bmod p$ by Fermat's little theorem. Then $(y-1)(y+1) \equiv 0 \bmod p$, and so $y \equiv \pm 1 \bmod p$.

Comment: I see that $y = x^{(p-1)/2}$ satisfies $y^2 \equiv 1 \bmod{p}$ by Fermat's little theorem and I see that implies $(y - 1)(y + 1) \equiv 0 \bmod{p}$.  That leads to the conclusion $y \equiv \pm 1 \bmod{p}$ which means I can't say for sure $y \equiv -1 \bmod{p}$.  However, in the original problem, we know $y = x^{(p-1)/2} \bmod{p}$ cannot be 1.  Therefore, $y \equiv -1 \bmod{p}$ is the only possibility left.  Thanks!